# What are valid return values for a Javascript Interface on an Android WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an Android WebView that has JavaScript that is calling Android methods through the addJavascriptInterface method:

```
myWebview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavascriptBridge(), "Android");

public class JavascriptBridge {

    public String getAString() {          
        return "my_str";
    }
}
```

This works fine. I want to return a list of ints to the WebView. Tried this:

```
public class JavascriptBridge {

    public int[] getMyInts() {          
        return new int[]{1,2,3};
    }
}
```

but calling this function in JS returns undefined:

```
var myInts = Android.getMyInts();
```

Is there a list of valid return types for an Android Javascript Interface? Is it only primitives?

Comment: Have you tried creating the array first, e.g., `var myInts = new Array();` then calling `myInts = Android.getMyInts();`?

Comment: AFAIK, it is only primitives. You can marshal more complex stuff to JSON, though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have not seen a list of valid types (for passing values to Java functions and to return), but only primitives and string seem to work.

You can use JSON (e.g. stringify and parse in Javascript, check various Java options at [json.org](http://json.org)

Answer (score 14):

You can return anything, primitives or Objects.  Objects are converted to strings via their toString() method.  If the JavascriptInterface method returns a JSON string (e.g. an Object who's toString() outputs JSON) you can then parse that string directly:

```
var array = JSON.parse(window.android.getSomeJsonThing());
```