# Passing object in Android WebAppInterface

Tags: java, android, json, android-webview, gson

I want to make a list of Card objects available over a WebAppInterface, but I only get an empty Json object on the WebView side. My dirty workaround is passing it as JSON end decoding it in the webview. Whats the right way?

```
// not working:
@JavascriptInterface
public List<Card> getCards() { return cards; }

// dirty:
@JavascriptInterface
public String getCards() { return gson.toJson(cards); }
```

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105059/what-are-valid-return-values-for-an-javascript-interface-on-an-android-webview

Comment: ok, thanks ;) I try to close the question as a duplicate