# Where's documentation on js type conversions for addJavascriptInterface?

Tags: android, android-webview

[addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) lets us inject a java object into the javascript of an Android web view. Where's the documentation on what java types each javascript type can be converted into in function parameter arguments for that object?

Some type conversions (strings, integers, etc) are obvious, but some are less so. What java type does a javascript list correspond to? How about an object? Or an [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer)?

Answer (score 0):

You must have a translator for this `Object` in the `addJavascriptInterface` signature..

> To bind a new interface between your JavaScript and Android code, call addJavascriptInterface(), **passing it a class instance to bind to your JavaScript and an interface name that your JavaScript can call to access the class**.

You must provide your `Javascript` a way to translate this objects, I guess you're looking for something like [JSON](http://json.org/), you have plenty of classes like `JSONObject.java` for `Map`s or `JSONArray.java` for `array`s or `List`s. [Here you can find more classes](http://json.org/java/).

**UPDATE**:
 If you take a look in the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) you can see how pass objects to `Javascript`.

```
class JsObject {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String toString() { return "injectedObject"; }
}
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "injectedObject");
webView.loadData("", "text/html", null);
webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(injectedObject.toString())");
```

And in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9522528/3850595) will confirm you **MUST** use JSON to parse them in the view...

> I have not seen a list of valid types (for passing values to Java functions and to return), but only primitives and string seem to work.
>   You can use JSON (e.g. stringify and parse in Javascript, check various Java options at json.org

Maybe is not the answer you were waiting form... but IMHO you don't have any other chance.

Comment: I think "interface name" refers to the global name of the variable referring to the object in javascript. I don't think that has to do with argument conversions. Thanks for the classes though.