# How to expose objects/properties to JavaScript via AddJavascriptInterface

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android, android-webview

I know that I can expose a "jsBridge" object to javascript in webview by

```
Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JsBridge(), 'jsBridge');
```

It seems inside the "JsBridge" class, we can only expose methods like

```
        [JavascriptInterface]
        [Export("myMethodName")]
        public void MyMethod(string message)
        {
           //some logic
        }
```

But I need some way to expose some objects or properties like bellow:

```
public ApiModule1 Module1 => _module1;
public ApiModule2 Module2 => _module2;
```

seems the "ExportAttribute" can only be applied to methods.

I am doing this because I need a way to expose only one single namespace at the JavaScript side, and still keep things organized by not stuffing everything into one object, that is;

```
jsBridge.Module1.someMethod(); 
jsBridge.Module2.someMethod();
```

Did I misunderstood some concepts here or is there are any other way to achieve this kind of feature?

Thank you very much.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/32491597/987000 , seem that android dose NOT support exporting anything but functions.

Comment: maybe you can expose a property as a pair of get/set methods?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expose properties directly. If you want to export any object create a getter for same in the interface you are exposing.